# Formik use setErrors method in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have an Formik component

```
<Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          enableReinitialize
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
            handleSubmitForm(values, id);
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
```

And I need to handle validation from API, but my request and error actions are different, so I need to use `useEffect` for handling errors.
How can I use `setErrors` method of my Formik in outside of `onSubmit` or in `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setErrors({...error})
}, [error])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue like this:
I have added to my `handleSubmitForm` `async` property like this:

```
const handleSubmitForm = async (data, id) => {
 ...
}
```

And not it returns a `promise`, and added global variable `let errorResolver = null;` outside of my function component, and added `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(error)) {
      if (errorResolver) {
        errorResolver(error);
      }
    }
  }, [error]);
```

then I have refactored my `onSubmit` like this:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
            handleSubmitForm(values, id).then(() => {
              new Promise(resolve => {
                errorResolver = resolve;
              }).then(response => {
                let errorObj = {};
                response.map(item => {
                  errorObj = { ...errorObj, ...item };
                });
                setErrors(errorObj);
              });
            });
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
```

So now when I do onSubmit it will wait still error object will receive value.
The final components looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import { Form, Formik } from 'formik';

let errorResolver = null;
export default function TableDataManager({ error, handleSubmitForm }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(error)) {
      if (errorResolver) {
        errorResolver(error);
      }
    }
  }, [error]);
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
        handleSubmitForm(values, id).then(() => {
          new Promise(resolve => {
            errorResolver = resolve;
          }).then(response => {
            let errorObj = {};
            // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
            response.map(item => {
              errorObj = { ...errorObj, ...item };
            });
            setErrors(errorObj);
          });
        });
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
    >
      ...
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

Not sure that the best solution, but it works.